# How to capture funds later when using Stripe's Checkout feature?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe's [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) feature. My product takes a few minutes to generate, so I want to place a hold on the funds, only charging the customer once their product is ready. Is it possible to do so without refactoring away from using this feature?

Comment: What you can do is to use the so-called `Auth and Capture` method where you put a hold on the fund without actually charging the customer and only `capture` the fund when the product is ready. You could set `capture_method=manual` when you are creating a checkout session. see https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-capture_method

Comment: I don’t believe I can do that when using the Checkout feature.

Comment: yes you can, take a look at https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-capture_method

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me:

```php
<?php
$amount = 50;

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

$session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'success_url' => 'reservation.success'.'?id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => 'reservation.cancel',
    'payment_intent_data' => [
        'capture_method' => 'manual',
    ],

    'line_items' => [[
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => "eur",
            'product_data'=> [
                'name'=> "My awesome product",
            ],
            'unit_amount'=> $amount * 100,
        ],
        'quantity' => 1
    ]],
    'mode' => 'payment',
]);

return redirect()->to($session->url);
```

This was done in laravel. You might need to adapt it a little to your needs.

Of course you need to

- adapt `$amount` to the amount you want to collect in €.
- change the `currency` if you need to
- set the route for `success_url`
- set the route for `cancel_url`

After calling this code the user is redirected to the session url, to make the payment, which is then reserved on his card.

You can then capture the payment later via:

```php
<?php
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

$session_id = 'THE_CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID';
$payment_intent = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve($session_id)-payment_intent;

$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($payment_intent);
// Capture all
$intent->capture();
// Alternative: Capture only a part of the reserved amount
// $intent->capture(['amount_to_capture' => 750]);
```

See also https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later